# How upload file if input take click automaticaly

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, input, selenide

I'm trying to write an e2e test for upload file using `selenide`, but face a problem.
Element `'input'` creates only after click at `'button'` and then input takes click.

JS code :

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.click();
```

How can I upload a file if input don't exist in DOM?

I'd like to use `selenide` native `uploadFile()` method. Perhaps for this I need to call some kind of JS script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked an example from Selenide's developers on how they suggest file uploading? It is not mandatory to have 'input' btw.
https://github.com/selenide/selenide/blob/master/src/test/java/integration/FileUploadTest.java